# Different display types for different posts on category page

Tags: php, categories

I was wondering what would be the best way to 'set' different display styles for different posts in the loop on a category page?

That's what I would like to end up with:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="section-one">
      <div class="first-post">First post</div>
      <div class="second-third-posts">
         <div class="second-post">Second post</div>
         <div class="third-post">Third post</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="section-two">
      <div>post 4...</div>
      <div>post 5...</div>
      <div>post 6...</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Might be, yes. Thanks... though I'm still confused.